# How to change content type of a lot of folders and subfolders at once?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, folder, content, office-365-developer

I have a lot of folders and subfolders on my Sharepoint who's content type I want to change.

Is there a way I can change the content type of several folders at once ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use SharePoint Online, chances are that you can use Flow. You can change the content type of an item with Flow with the action **Update file properties**. If the library allows management of content types, there will be a field where you can select the content type for the item.

Conceptually:

- something triggers the workflow. Can be a manual trigger if you use a one-time only flow
- Action **Get Files (Properties only)** -- this will return a list of items in the library, folders and documents
- Action **Apply to each** - The action will be built automatically if you create an action that references the **Get Files (properties only)** action. It will perform the following actions on each item in the list that was returned above. It's like a "for-next" loop.
- Action **condition** -- Start the actions in the loop with a condition to determine if the current item meets the criteria. Put the next action into the **Yes** branch
- Action **Update file properties** - set the content type in the dialog for the item properties.

You might also be able to do that with a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow, but Flow is a lot easier to troubleshoot.

Edit: This kind of flow has not been prepared as a template and you will need to write it from scratch.

In Flow, click **My Flows**, then **New** > **Create from blank** and again **Create from blank**.

In the box "Search connectors and triggers" type **manual**. Now you should see the **Flow button for mobile**  trigger. Click that to create a flow that can be manually started.

In the Flow designer, click **New step**, then click **SharePoint** and find the action **Get files (properties onlY)**

[image]

Specify the site and the library.

Then insert a new step, select SharePoint and find the action to **Update file properties**. Specify the same site and library as in the previous step and in the ID field use the Dynamic content picker to pick the ID from the Get files step. That will automatically insert the loop you need.

[image]

Now the **Apply to each** has been wrapped around the **Update file properties**. Continue configuring the **Update file properties**, which will now show the columns available to the document library.

Every action inside the loop will be applied to all documents returned by the **Get files** action.

When you have added all the actions, save the flow and then return to the My Flows page. Here you will see a triangle like a play button on a music player when you hover the mouse over the row with your flow. Click this to start the flow manually.

[image]

If you need more help with Flow, you may want to watch a few of the tutorials available with a brief search.

Comment: Thank you so much @teylyn for the explanation but I'm a total beginner this and don't understand it  completely.    




I do have SharePoint online and when I click on flow, I see a lot of templates I don't see **Update file properties** . 

The closest one that I see is **Update SharePoint file properties with location fetched from Bing Maps**




I'm  stuck there and I don't really want to go to every folder and subfolder and change the content type manually. The flow would be a one time only flow and that's it.

Comment: I added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

thank you @teylyn.
Unfortunately I have been unsuccessful, even after reading and watching some tutorials.

1. I'm struggling with Site Address,Library Name and ID.
   [image]

and this is my documents library.
it has these two folders and subfolders. The content type of all these folders should be changed

[image]

The content type of all of these should be changed to Enhanced Folder content type.
docType set to unassigned but that is not super important.
[image]

thank you very much.